# In three.js library, how convert face4 into two face3 not overlapping triangles?

Tags: three.js, geometry

I have a face4 (quad face), and i need to get two face3 (triangle face) without overlapping.

Comment: Just want to make clear, face4 has been [removed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18654083/4405465)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a utility that will triangulate quads for you:

```
THREE.GeometryUtils.triangulateQuads( geometry );
```

EDIT: This method no longer exists.

three.js r.70

Answer (score 6):

A face4 with vertices a,b,c,d is equivalent to two face3's. One with vertices a,b,c and the other with vertices a,c,d.