# three.js : face4 generates triangle instead of square

Tags: javascript, geometry, three.js

i'm trying to generate a square with tree.js custom Geometry.
but this code

```
var cubeGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
cubeGeo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -25,  25, -25 ) );
cubeGeo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  25,  25, -25 ) );
cubeGeo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -25, -25, -25 ) );
cubeGeo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  25,  -25, -25 ) );
cubeGeo.faces.push( new THREE.Face4( 0, 1, 2, 3, new THREE.Vector3( 0,  0,  1 ), 0xffffff, 0) );

    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
  cubeGeo,  
  //new THREE.CubeGeometry(50, 50, 50),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x696969, emissive: 0x696969, specular:0x696969, shininess: 15})
);
```

generates triangle
can somebody explain me why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it should be drawing something like a bow-tie. The vertex order is not correct. Swap the last two vertices.

Comment: swapped, but it is drawing nothing  now to me

Comment: http://codepen.io/usf/pen/LaDwh - there is my full code, i left vertices in original order

Comment: Just did this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2yped/. In your above update it is probably the side you are looking at it so make it `side: THREE.DoubleSide` to see it.

Comment: Yes but generally you should not be using it. It is an expense on the GPU.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is with the THREE.Face4. It has been removed in the last version. In [GitHub Three.js - Wiki - Migration](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) we can read:

> r59 -> r60
>
> Face4 is removed. Use 2 Face3 to emulate it.

And the reason why you see a triangle instead of a square is that:

```
THREE.Face4 = function ( a, b, c, d, normal, color, materialIndex ) {

    return new THREE.Face3( a, b, c, normal, color, materialIndex );

};
```

Answer (score 10):

Three.Face4 is deprecated.

Here's how you use 2 `Face3` to make a square:

```
function drawSquare(x1, y1, x2, y2) { 

    var square = new THREE.Geometry(); 

    //set 4 points
    square.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x1,y2,0) );
    square.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x1,y1,0) );
    square.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x2,y1,0) );
    square.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x2,y2,0) );

    //push 1 triangle
    square.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0,1,2) );

    //push another triangle
    square.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0,3,2) );

    //return the square object with BOTH faces
    return square;
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, but doesn't answer the question, which is about `Face4`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. `Face4` is no longer supported.